# How to parse wikitext tables HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-negation

Wikicode to parse the table is

```
{| class="wikitable"
|-
! Header 1
! Header 2
! Header 3
|-
| row 1, cell 1
| row 1, cell 2
| row 1, cell 3
|-
| row 2, cell 1
| row 2, cell 2
| row 2, cell 3
|}
```

I need to parse it to HTML format like `<table> </table>` using regex in this [file](http://goessner.net/download/prj/wiky/wiky.js)?

Comment: What is that file you linked? Does it convert wikitables into html? If not, why use it at all?

Comment: It does not convert the wikitables into html but it converts the rest. I need to add the function here, so that it can also convert wikitables.

Comment: Oh, okay. Would it not be better to just tell us what you need--a regex and a replacer function, or whatever--so that we can focus on the problem instead of parsing the whole library before we start?

Comment: I just need a regex function which would parse the wikitables. That's all.

Comment: Oh, okay. "Using regex in this file" threw me off. Sounds like we don't need to worry about that file at all...

What features need to be captured? We have an example, but how does the syntax work for a wikitable? And how should it be translated into HTML? Maybe just the HTML for the example in the post would suffice.

Comment: I need to parse it to HTML elements: `<table>, <tr>, <td> or <th>`. Syntax for a wikitable is given above.

Comment: Yeah, could you humour me and show what that table would look like HTML-ified?

Comment: I didn't get you? Isn't it possible?

Comment: it's perfectly possible; and not that hard. But if you want the details to be right with our answers, you have to give details in the question. I'm going to assume the table would look like this: `<table class="wikitable"><thead><tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td><td>row 1, cell 3</td></tr><tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td><td>row 2, cell 3</td></tbody></table>`. Is that right?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: Okay. I'll just make a function that does it all and returns the HTML as a string.

Comment: Thanks +1 :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

- Find the table

  - Find each row
  - If the row has `=` store it as table attributes
  - If the row has `!` at the start, render header row

    - Get and render each header
  - Otherwise, it's a normal row

    - Get and render each cell
- Render the table: put all the pieces together, and return

https://jsfiddle.net/n1dp3fcs/2/

```
var attrs = "", headers = "", rows = "";
function renderTables(wiki) {
  wiki.replace(findTable, parseTable);
  var HTML = "<table" + (attrs ? " " + attrs : "") + ">" +
    (headers ? "<thead>" + headers + "</thead>" : "") +
    (rows ? "<tbody>" + rows + "</tbody>" : "") +
  "</table>";
  attrs = headers = rows = "";
  return HTML;
}

var findTable = /\{\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|\}/g,
    parseTable = function(match, content) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(content.split(newRow), renderRow);
    };

var newRow = /\s*\|-\s*(?:\|\s*)?/g,
    renderRow = function(content) {
      console.log("tr", content, arguments);
      if (content.indexOf("=") !== -1) { console.log("attrs"); attrs += content; }
      else if (content[0] === "!") { console.log("th"); headers += "<tr>" + content.replace(findHeader, renderHeader) + "</tr>"; }
      else { console.log("td"); rows += "<tr>" + content.replace(findCol, renderCol) + "</tr>"; }
    };

var findHeader = /\s*!\s*([^!]+?)(?=\s*!|$)/g, renderHeader = "<th>$1</th>";

var findCol = /(?:^\s*|\s*\|\s*)([^\|]+?)(?=\s*\||$)/g, renderCol = "<td>$1</td>";
```

Comment: It works great. But there is a problem, I didnt correctly write the tables code for wikitext. I have updated it. Can you recheck it? Also, is there a way if I can add this code into this (http://goessner.net/download/prj/wiky/wiky.js) ?

Comment: Try that. I can't really spend hours figuring out how that file works. You could always get in touch with whoever made it and ask if he'd like to add it. My name's Thomas Giles, `GitHub: wthit56` if he could credit me. Or you could've probably just asked if he could fix his table rendering code to the new version or whatever's going on there.

Comment: Essentially, I've just done a load of work for you for free. Just a heads up, this forum is more for asking questions, not getting people to write entire pieces of code for you, and then reimplementing it in someone else's library. You're kinda lucky I just find these things fun, but I'm not going to look at someone else's code and splice in my work.